# Sorting recyclerview by recently accessed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room

I am doing a side project of making an app (with Java since I already know it). I have a recyclerview which loads some data via the room database library. The elements of the recyclerview are clickable.

My problem is I want the user to be able to sort the recyclerview so that the most recently accessed items go to the top.

My original idea was to assign the entities to have two variables - a String list_name which also serves as the id, and an Int order_of_access. Also, in my ViewModel I have a getAllLists method which returns a livedata list. I have an onChanged listener in the fragment activity which nicely updates the recyclerview when data is added/removed.

When the user adds a new list, it is assigned an order_of_access of the listsize (+1). But when the user deletes a group of lists, or clicks on a list, I want to update the order_of_access, say with an updateOrderAccess method.

1. Do you think this is the best way of doing what I want?
2. Where should I place updateOrderAccess and how would you recommend it be written? Since the method getAllLists returns livedata, it is tempting to put updateOrderAccess in an observer in the fragment (in onChanged) - but this will obviously create an infinite loop. It seems more in the correct philosophy to put it in the ViewModel, but then how would you suggest the updateOrderAccess method to be written? I'm having some trouble conceptualising what I need.

I hope the question is not too vague - I will update it if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

> Where should I place updateOrderAccess and how would you recommend it
> be written?

I am so sure that you must write it in the view model, as long as `updateOrderAccess()` is editing the list which is observable then you have andexpose by that the ui state then you have to put it in view model, and the observers will be notified ( in this case it is recycle view) and it will redraw the list in the order you offered.

*note: do not you ever update the state(ui data) outside the state holder so you implement UDF (unidirectional Data Flow) pattern.*
[image]

*see the references below to read more about UDF so you never get confused where to declare your functions by letting the architicture lead you:*

[Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture)

[ui layer](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer)

[state holders and ui state](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/stateholders)

> Do you think this is the best way of doing what I want?

i am not very sure that i got exactly what your app do, but it seems like you want to re-order the elements of recycle view depending on the ui event (click) or data change (deleting or adding new element), now you have two choices:

### if the order is very importnat to you that much you want to keep it even if the app has been destroyed

then you have to add a field in the room entity represent the ordering (let us call it *order*) and whenever the user click on the recycle view you have to update the rooms field "*order*" which is "*flow*" or "*liveData*" or any observable type, that will tell the view model that there is a changing in the data, now the view model have to re-order the new data by the field "*order*" and pass it to the recycle view to show it.

### if your app do not have to save the order changes after the app been destroyed

then you can simply do that:
create list which is called "*orderedList*" you will put the list items in it by the right order, and another list called "*unorderlist*" which have `getAllLists`

1. for the first case where the ordering is being changed by user click, you
   can declare a function in viewModel then use it in the ui
   controller (your activity or fragment), so whenever the list item is
   clicked this function just re-order the *orderedList* elements ( which
   is observable, so the changes reflect on the ui ) just by change the
   clicked item position to the front of the list.
2. for the second case where the ordering changes by data changes like
   add or delet a list item in the database, then you have to compare
   the legnth of *orderlist* and *unorderlist* legnth, if *unorderList* is
   longer then it is an add situation else it is a delete situation, in
   adding case just add the last item of *unorderList* to the *orderList*,
   else you have to check the deleted item and delete it from
   orderList.